# ArrayList printing duplicate vlaues

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I want to check two arraylist and then insert to another arrayList. But when I do I get the duplicate values. How to solve this issue and removing duplicates.
I will get the median and check whether the median is greater than or less than then insert the values in third arraylist.

```
public static void cluster() {
  Kmeans kk = new Kmeans();
  for (int x = 0; x < cluster1.size() && cluster1 != null; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < cluster2.size() && cluster2 != null; y++) {
      String s1 = cluster1.get(x);
      String s2 = cluster2.get(y);
      try {
        int median = kk.distance(s1, s2);
        if (s1.length() > median) {
          kmcluster1.add(s1);
          kmcluster2.add(s2);
        }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
public static int median(String q, String w) {
  int h = q.length();
  int h1 = w.length();
  int kk = 0;
  if (h > h1) {
    kk = h - h1;
    return kk;
  } else kk = h1 - h;
  return kk;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: can you spot the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your code:

```
x < cluster1.size() && cluster1 != null; // will not prevent a null pointer exception
```

You should either use

```
cluster1 != null && x < cluster1.size();
```

or preferably do a NULL check just once before entering the loop.

And, yes to answer your question use a `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`. It will ignore addition of duplicates quietly (without throwing exceptions). Instantiate your clusters as follows:

```
Set<String> kmcluster1 = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> kmcluster2 = new HashSet<String>();
```

Use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList` and a `LinkedHashSet` instead of `LinkedList` whenever you do not want your data structure to contain any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList`s allow for duplicate values by design.  If you want a data structure that forbids duplicates, consider using an instance of a `Set` instead.

Comment: you haven't supplied enough code here, but i'm assuming that `kmcluster1` and `kmcluster2` are the `ArrayList` instances you are referencing in your original question.  If you want these data structures to ignore duplicate values, they should be declared as some kind of `Set` - a `HashSet` or `TreeSet` would work.  If you can't redeclare these collections as a different type, then just check to see if the value already exists in the collection (using the `.contains(...)` method) prior to adding it.